# Powershell | adding double quotation to a string

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

I want to print a variable with double quotation but Powershell automatically print without them so anyone knows?

for example print = mobile number is: "9847636782" << I want to print the number with the double quotation

I have tried this way :
write-host "mobile number is: "$mobilenum"  "

and didn't work so please help

Comment: See: [Including quote characters in a string](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules#including-quote-characters-in-a-string): `write-host "mobile number is: ""$mobilenum"" "`

Answer (score 4):

```
Write-Host "mobile number is: `"$mobilenum`""
```

[image]

Please find detailed information about escaping [here](https://www.rlmueller.net/PowerShellEscape.htm).

> Finally, if your PowerShell strings are quoted with double quotes, then any double quote characters in the string must be escaped with the backtick "`". Alternatively, the embedded double quote characters can be doubled (replace any embedded " characters with "").

[image]